# Android soundPool supported Extension?

Tags: android, soundpool

I wrote this code in the `onCreate()` method, but nothing was played !

```
   SoundPool mSound = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
   AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);          

   int soundID = mSound.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);

   int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
   mSound.play(soundID, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

**Question #1 :** Is there a problem with my code ? Did I do it wrongly ?

If No,

**Question #2 :** My sound is `.amr` file. Is it supported by `SoundPool` ? What are the supported types ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine, but you should wait some time after loading and before play. It takes some time to load. You can check if the sound is loaded with the help of "OnLoadCompleteListener".

Comment: You are TOTALLY right. I figured it out and forgot to update the question :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet looks fine. For the list of supported formats refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core). It looks like you have to try .mp3 or .ogg or .wav instead. AMR codecs are supported according to the docs, but the files have to be in .3gp format.

Comment: Sorry if it obvious, but by .wave do you mean .wav?